# How to handle SaxParserException in java

Tags: java, xml

I had a xml file which doesn't have  tag. It contains only end tags. I need to read this xml file. Can any one let me know the way to read these kind of xml files?

Sample Xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<students>
    <student>
        <name>John</name>
       </grade>
        <age>12</age>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Mary</name>
        <grade>A</grade>
        </age>
    </student>
    <student>
       </name>
        <grade>A</grade>
        <age>18</age>
    </student>
</students>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not XML, so you can't read it using an XML parser.

You need to find out what the grammar is, and then write a parser for that grammar.

Of course, the benefit of standards like XML is that if people use them, it saves you writing a lot of code. If people don't use them, you're on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You could pre-process it to make it a regular xml, and then use standard SAX/JAXP/DOM